# Screen recording through webView's function in android

Tags: android, webview, android-permissions, screen-recording, mediadevices

I am opening a webpage (external) on webview in android. On that webpage, there is a button for screen recording. Screen recording is working fine if I open it on Desktop systems/Laptop.
But when I am opening this webpage on android's webview, screen recording functionality is not working. It is saying that: **navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia is not a function**

Inshort, webview's screen recorder is not working on android.

Comment: which browser is set as default on your mobile?

Comment: "Screen recording is working fine if I open it on Desktop systems/Laptop" -- at minimum, that will vary by browser. There is no requirement for every Web browser to support this. "webview's screen recorder is not working on android" -- again, there is no requirement for every Web browser to support this. If you are writing an Android app, you can use the media projection APIs for screen recording.